# Построение правильной архитектуры

Tags: c++, архитектура, проектирование, полиморфизм

Наткнулся на затык при проектировании архитектуры. Имею абстрактный класс *Model* и двух наследников - *Model1* и *Model2*. *Model1* обладает членом типа *int(a)*, а *Model2* - *const char*(b)*. Также имеется абстрактный класс *Render* и два наследника - *Render1* и *Render2*. *Render* предоставляет чистую виртуальную функцию - член *draw*, которая принимает тип *Model**. Теперь же, в классе *Render1* в методе *draw* я выполняю некоторые действия, и мне нужен доступ к члену *a*, класса *Model1*. В свою очередь тоже самое требуется в классе *Render2* доступ к члену *b* класса *Model2*. По задумке, в класс *Render2* не может быть передан класс *Model1* и наоборот. Как поступить в такой ситуации? Базовый код, использующий полиморфизм, приведён ниже:

```
class Model
{
public:
    virtual void init() = 0;
};

class Model1 : public Model
{
    int a;
public:
    void init() override
    {
        a = 48;
    }
};

class Model2 : public Model
{
    const char* b;
public:
    void init() override
    {
        b = "test";
    }
};

class Render
{
public:
    virtual void draw(Model* m) = 0;
};

class Render1: public Render
{
public:
    void draw(Model* m) override
    {
        // здесь сделать что - то с a
    }
};

class Render2 : public Render
{
public:
    void draw(Model* m) override
    {
        // здесь сделать что - то с b
    }
};
```

P.S.: я понимаю, что *Render'ы* не должны знать, кто в них приходит(какой экземпляр класса), но ничего лучшего никак не могу придумать. Посоветуйте, как в таком случае стоит поступить. Полиморфизм и наследование использовал потому что классы слишком общие.
P.S.S.: про dynamic_cast знаю, но это тоже рушит архитектуру, я пытаюсь избежать этого

**UPD1:**
При использовании визитора я бы хотел разделить возможности наследников, так как в случае использования одного визитора подключаются много библиотек. А хотелось бы в определенном хейдере определенную библиотеку. Иными словами, можно ли сделать вместо этого:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

class Visitor 
{
public:
  virtual void visit(Foo &ref) = 0;
  virtual void visit(Bar &ref) = 0;

  virtual ~Visitor() = default;
};

class GetType : public Visitor 
{
public:
  std::string value;

public:
  void visit(Foo &ref) override 
  {
    value = "Foo";
  }
  void visit(Bar &ref) override 
  {
    value = "Bar";
  }

};
```

Вот так:

```
class Foo;
class Bar;

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(Foo& ref) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Bar& ref) = 0;

    virtual ~Visitor() = default;
};

class GetTypeFoo : public Visitor
{
public:
    std::string value;

public:
    void visit(Foo& ref) override
    {
        value = "Foo";
    }
    void visit(Bar& ref) override
    {
        // empty
    }

};

class GetTypeBar : public Visitor
{
public:
    std::string value;

public:
    void visit(Foo& ref) override
    {
        // empty
    }
    void visit(Bar& ref) override
    {
        value = "Bar";
    }

};
```

Ну и вызываться, соответственно, будет нужный метод в нужный момент.

Comment: возможно стоит посмотреть на https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

Comment: @ExplodingKitten сдесь скорее нужны визиторы, нежели мост. То бишь создаёте виртуальную функцию draw в model в которую передаёте render - в ней вы имеете доступ ко всем данным определенным в модели

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch идея с визитором мне очень понравилась, спасибо! Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, как поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: @Range обычно в таких случаях следует публиковать новый вопрос нежели дополнять предыдущий, так как это два разных вопроса. Что касается вопрос - конечно, можно делать и так, в этом нет никаких проблем

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch можете опубликовать ответ при визитора, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае отлично подойдет такой паттерн программирования как [visitor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). Тобишь создаете виртуальную функцию `draw` в базовом классе `Model` в которую передаете объект `Render`. Так вы избавитесь от проблемы определения типов, так  как объект априори знает о том, какой у него тип.

В итоге у вас будет два базовых типа: один для `visitor`-ов, второй для объектов, принимающих визиторы. Количество производных (от базового класса) визиторов не ограничено, но следует помнить, что в случае добавления нового класса принимающего визитор вы должны обеспечить поддержку нового класса всеми визиторами! Это создает некоторую сложность, но если часть (или все крому одного) визиторов не должна что-либо делать с объектом нового типа, то для упрощение имплементации можно определить в базовом классе `visitor` все функции не как абстрактные, а с пустой реализацией.